# Bootbox - Confirm Modal DIalog Box requires Callback function ... but I have one

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootbox

Why does the below code return an error:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#chkIssueCredit").change(function () {
            if (!$(this).prop('checked')) {
                bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you do not want to issue a credit? Please confirm."), function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        $(this).prop('checked', true);
                    }
                }
                return false;

                //if (!confirm("Are you sure you do not want to issue a credit? Please confirm.")) {
                //    $(this).prop('checked', true);
                //};
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What error does the code produce for you? Please [edit] the question to remove the repetition, and add the error message. If possible turn the question into an [mcve] by adding the appropriate html and turning it into an executable snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the confirm method right after the first parameter (the message). Try this one here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#chkIssueCredit").change(function () {
            if (!$(this).prop('checked')) {
                bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you do not want to issue a credit? Please confirm.", function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        $(this).prop('checked', true);
                    }
                });
                return false;

                //if (!confirm("Are you sure you do not want to issue a credit? Please confirm.")) {
                //    $(this).prop('checked', true);
                //};
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can you see the difference?